# How to switch two numbered arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say I have an array like this `[[5,6], [7,8]]`

I want to run a method or something so it becomes `[[6,5], [8,7]]`

```
public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<Integer>> numlist = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> somelist = new ArrayList<>();
    somelist.add(5);
    somelist.add(6);
    numlist.add(somelist);

    List<Integer> somelist2 = new ArrayList<>();
    somelist2.add(7);
    somelist2.add(8);
    numlist.add(somelist2);

    // created [[5,6], [7,8]]
    System.out.println(numlist);

    }
}
```

I'm not really use too java but in python I would iterate through `numlist` and use tuples to make `numlist[i][0], numlist[i][1] = numlist[i][1], numlist[i][0]`, `i` being the iter number

How would I do that in Java?

Comment: `temp = x[0]; x[0] = x[1]; x[1] = temp;`, i.e. standard non-Java-specific value swapping. Or rather, since they are **lists**, not arrays: `temp = x.get(0); x.set(0, x.get(1)); x.set(1, temp);`. Or simpler yet: `x.add(x.remove(0));`, which moves first element to the end.

Comment: You can not translate English to Russian word by word. If you do it you'll lose the meaning.The above mentioned code works, but you've to know difference between arrays and lists before you can do anything meaningful with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution with a reverseOrder method in a Collections class in java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<Integer>> numlist = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        List<Integer> somelist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        somelist.add(5);
        somelist.add(6);
        Integer[] aa = new Integer[somelist.size()];
        Arrays.sort(somelist.toArray(aa), Collections.reverseOrder());
        somelist.clear();

        for(int i  =0;i<aa.length;i++)
        {
            somelist.add(aa[i]);
        }
        numlist.add(somelist);

        List<Integer> somelist2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        somelist2.add(7);
        somelist2.add(8);
        aa = new Integer[somelist2.size()];
        Arrays.sort(somelist2.toArray(aa), Collections.reverseOrder());
        somelist2.clear();

        for(int i  =0;i<aa.length;i++)
        {
            somelist2.add(aa[i]);
        }


        numlist.add(somelist2);

        // created [[6, 5], [8, 7]]
        System.out.println(numlist);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (List<Integer> list : numlist) {
    result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(list.get(1), list.get(0))));
}
// created [[6,5], [8,7]]
System.out.println(result);
```